# zend framework2 issue while installing composer.phar

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have downloaded the zf2 skeleton application and after that,
WHile running

php composer.phar install the following error comes

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "http://packagist.org/p/zendframework/skeleton-application$65da2ae415c0  
  9e4b944964efe964f41b27e5b8bbe9cd7345515b4d2eea8ee5e6.json" file could not b  
  e downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Please give me some advice

Comment: have you tried to `git clone` ? or did you download the `.tar.gz` file?

Answer (score 0):

this is an open issue you can find it here :
[github Composer issues 2624](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2624)

Maybe some solutions in comments may help you.

Try :

Update composer.phar with

> composer.phar self-update

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're running a web filter, especially *K9 Web Protection*, uninstall that first and retry. If the problem persists, read ahead:

The problem is that Composer downgrades to *http* requests after the first *https* request to the server. This is done to improve performance/speed and to ensure file integrity/security via the sha256 hashes. In any case, this will cause a 10053 error (errno=10053 An established connection was aborted
 by the software in your host machine ... failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!) on some machines.

The reason this happens to some people and not others seems to be the manner in which your ISP handles *http* requests. In my case, they're re-routed through a caching proxy; which doesn't work well with the way Composer crafts its *http* requests. That's what happened with me - others may have a different cause. In any case, the fix is to force Composer to use *https* requests instead of *http* requests:

Add the following to your Composer installation's config file (composer.json). In Windows, you may find this file at C:\Users{Your Username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer.

```
"repositories": [
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org/"
}
],
```

Then go ahead and create your project again with the same command you had used: php composer.phar install. It should work now.